# How to store audio in multipart using json on server php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");//database connectivity
$uid=$_POST['uid'];//user's id
$meeting_id=$_POST['meeting_id'];//meeting id
// Create directory if it does not exist
if(!is_dir("audioupload/".$uid."/".$_SESSION["uid"]."/"))   
    {
        mkdir("audioupload/".$uid."/".$_SESSION["uid"]."/");
    }
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['audio']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension'];
$audio_name = "meeting_id".$meeting_id.".".$ext;
// Move the uploaded file
$upload=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"], "audioupload/".$uid."/".$_SESSION["uid"] ."/". $audio_name);
$sql="INSERT INTO `audio`(`uid`,`meeting_id`,`audio`) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$meeting_id."','".$audio_name."')";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result1)   
{
    $sql1="select * from `audio` where `uid`='$_POST[uid]'";     
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
if($count>0)
{
    $emparray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {            
        $emparray=array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => "Audio saved Successfully!",);

    }          
}   
else 
{
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
   $emparray=array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "Incorrect Data!",                
            );
}
echo json_encode($emparray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);      
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

this is my code for audio api. 
[image: json response from app incorrect]
[image: json response from postman tool correct]

i got to different results from same code. postman tool give me proper result whereas app doest give. wts the problem ?

Comment: What is the problem? Any error? And that extra `,` inside your `$emparray` will cause for an error

Comment: bro i get correct response from postman tool . and not get correct response from mobile app. please go through with images you will get my issue